# Assignability rules of union function types

Tags: typescript

Let's take the [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-3.html#improved-behavior-for-calling-union-types) from TS 3.3 docs:

```
type Fruit = "apple" | "orange";
type Color = "red" | "orange";

type FruitEater = (fruit: Fruit) => number;
type ColorConsumer = (color: Color) => string;

type FnUnion = FruitEater | ColorConsumer
```

I thought, the following function would be assignable to `FnUnion`
:

```
declare function foo(v: Fruit & Color): number | string
```

, as someone told me, functions are contravariant in parameters and covariant in the return type. But consider following:

```
declare let fn: FnUnion
declare function foo(v: Fruit & Color): number | string
declare function foo2(v: Fruit | Color): number
declare function foo3(v: Fruit | Color): string

fn = foo // error, why?
fn = foo2 // works
fn = foo3 // works
```

I am interested in the general assignability rules for union functions in above case. `foo2` and `foo3` are assignable to `fn`. But why isn't `foo` assignable?

I am sure to miss some TS knowledge here, appreciate answers. Thanks! PS: Here is a [sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=16&ssc=19&pln=9&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgTgVwJbCgXigIgIZjAGwkygB8sB7ObAOwHMiBuAWAChRIoBhc-S9LOBAAmxMpko16mZi1bto8ZMACi2YBDj8AFADNEKAFyx9wAJToAfFGoIAtgCMNM+Vx6Vu1AM52N2gMZucEbcvHDmaFaewHBIdDJy4ArUAKrUSOTU-IooquqaZCHuGd62GqysQhB++NiCUISoOtRGMClpGRVVNXU6CNR+wOmZOuTkWgBuLSZQAGSuoaZGNg6+ZFExdJ3VtdC9-YMZUCPkAEwTU0qk85SL1naOcFvdu30DQ0ejAMznxpcFgbd1rFaOUWE1+McoAB6KFQDRwSgAGigAHcABYgAD8rHBGGOJ2hsJRlAA1p4cZk8V9CajSZ4gA).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a value is assignable to a union type `S | T` then it must either be assignable to `S`, or assignable to `T`, or both. Now consider the following function:

```js
function foo(v: Fruit & Color): number | string {
    return Math.random() > 0.5 ? 23 : 'bar';
}
```

The function `foo` is not assignable to the type `FruitEater`, because it sometimes returns a string; and it's also not assignable to the type `ColorConsumer`, because it sometimes returns a number. Therefore, since `foo` is assignable to neither type, it is also not assignable to the union of those two types. QED.

But there's another problem: even if we change the return types of `FruitEater`, `ColorConsumer` and `foo` so that they're all the same, `foo` still isn't assignable to the union. It doesn't eat `'apple'` so it's not a `FruitEater`, and it doesn't consume `'red'` so it's not a `ColorConsumer`.

So in general, the union of two function types `(arg: A) => B` and `(arg: C) => D` is a subtype of the function type `(arg: A & C) => (B | D)`, but not identical to it.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful (especially the last sentence)! I think, I switched up assignability with invocation rules. For example given `declare const fn2: FnUnion`, you can invoke `f2` only with `"orange"` (`Fruit & Color`) and get `number | string` as return type - what I defined as `foo`. Second thing I mixed up: one function returning `number | string` is different from a union of functions, where one returns `number`, the other `string`.

Answer (score 3):

Just to be clear, `&` is intersection and `|` is union. This means that:

```
Fruit & Color //=> "orange"
Fruit | Color //=> "apple" | "orange" | "red"
```

Which means that this:

```
type FnUnion = FruitEater | ColorConsumer
```

Is a function that accepts all fruits, or a function that accepts all colors.

The following is valid usage of that type:

```
const colorFn: FnUnion = (color: Color) => 'a color'
colorFn('red')
colorFn('orange')

const fruitFn: FnUnion = (fruit: Fruit) => 123
fruitFn('apple')
fruitFn('orange')
```

Note: it must be one or the other. It must accept all fruits *or* it must accept all colors.

However, the `Fruit & Color` type can only be `'orange'`. So you are assigning a function that can *only* accept `'orange'` to a type that allows acceptance of either `'orange'|'red'` or `'orange'|'apple'`. This means that `'red'` or `'apple'` could never be passed as an argument, where `FnUnion` says that one or the other should be allowed.

And so typescript, rightly, complains that the types are not compatible.

---

Additionally, Typescript knows the union type, but also what member of the union it knows the value to be at certain points in the control flow.

When you cast to `FnUnion` like this:

```
const colorFn = ((color: Color) => 'a color') as FnUnion
```

You're telling TS that which member of the union it is is unknowable, since it can no longer discriminate based on argument type.

Therefore, it seems that the only safe inference is the one argument the two types have in common. Which, I realize, is exactly the function type it would not let you assign directly.

But I think the key difference is knowing which member of the union your function is.

```
// member known: ColorConsumer
const colorFn: FnUnion = (color: Color) => 'a color'

// member known: FruitEater
const fruitFn: FnUnion = (fruit: Fruit) => 123

// member unknown due to cast to less specific type.
//   only common arguments are allowed,
//   and only return types for those common arguments
const unknownFn: FnUnion = ((some: 'orange') => 'unknown') as FnUnion

// type is concretely known, but is not a match to any member.
const invalidFn: FnUnion = (some: 'orange') => 'invalid'
// ^ type error
```

`FnUnion` says it's one or the other, and if it doesn't know which one then it's the intersection of both. What you are trying to say the type is known and it's not either the members, but the intersection of both. This is what's incompatible.

But as you discovered with `as FnUnion` you can make typescript forget what it knows about something with a type cast.

All this means that what type something is *inferred* to be is not always the type that it could be *assigned* to be.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not sure concerning the example with `colorFn` and `fruitFn` - those functions should trigger a compile error when invoked with `"red"` respectively `"apple"`. My assumption is, TS was too "smart" and implicitly narrowed your functions via control flow analysis. When you use a type assertion to enforce, that the function are of type `FnUnion`, then there will be an error.

Comment: like [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgTgVwJbCgXigIgIZjAGwkygB8sB7ObAOwHMiBuAKFEigGFz9L0s4IAJsTKZKNepmYtw0eMmABRbMAhxeACgBmiFAC5YO4AEp0APijUEAWwBGq5q2iducTtQDO11RoDGXSvrOlCZo5u7AcEh0Uo6w1ACq1Ejk1LxyKEoqamRBrimeVqpMTH4eqH4uMNT6VYnJqRjq6hUBHP5wIeYA5NhQLXBdJtjucXUpJe1V6l38AoMTldTTYnQQ8xNlUNryVTUJSSkaWoY1hp1QAIwATADMQyO1B9RM2yhTPXiE86-A7yv0gyAA)

Comment: Good question! What type something is inferred to be is not always the type that it could be assigned to be. See my edit.